# Стилизация TextField

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Есть макет и нужно сделать поиск как там. Можно было бы и как-то по-другому, но заказчик нервный, так что нужно именно так. Учу flutter всего неделю, так что мне тяжело такое реализовать и мои потуги выглядят криво, а делать надо срочно. Прошу помощи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге сделал вот так:

```
CupertinoTextField(
                prefix: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/ic_search.svg")),
                placeholder: "Enter Email",
                suffix: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/ic_micro.svg")),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0x26767680),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              )
```